# Does a completed COMMIT statement imply it is done committing?

Tags: sql

Once a commit statement has completed, does that imply it is actually done committing? Or does it mean the commit action has been completed, but it could still be committing in the background?

Comment: Are you talking about a two-phase commit, XA, or vanilla commit?

Comment: What is your actual question? Once a commit has completed, it has completed and all sessions will see the new data. It may be, however, that the DBMS has done that in memory only yet and will write the data to disk later.

Comment: Also, some non-database related services that participate in the transaction (such as JMS) can delay the commit/rollback operations (maybe using store & forward).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Once a `COMMIT` command completes successfully, the operation is done, and changes are permanently recorded. There is no notion of background process that would need to somehow finalize the operation.

Here is a quote taken for [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html):

> `COMMIT` commits the current transaction, making its changes permanent.

As another example, [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) says:

> Use the `COMMIT` statement to end your current transaction and make permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single unit. This statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and releases transaction locks.